# Synchronization in a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, multithreading, function

I am working on a helpDesk Web application.

I am generating a unique complaint_id from one function
These function can be called by 3 users at time, normal user,super user and admin

when any user clicks on New complaint I am inserting a blank row in Complaint table and return that unique complaint_id to to caller .

But it may happen that all the 3 users have call the function at he same time and hence amy cause problem in generating the the Complaint id

as this function is shared there can be problem generating the id.
I only know it can solved used threads but how I don't know that 
I have very little knowledge about threads

The Get id Function is the common function
this function calls a stored procedure .

will it create problem if all 3 types of users call the function at same time
here is the code

```
    public string Getid(AddComplaint_DAO p)
    {
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        string strConnection;
        SqlDataAdapter adpt = null;

        try
        {
            strConnection = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Connetionstring2"];
            con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);
            cmd = new SqlCommand("GetId", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_CompDate", SqlDateTime.Null);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_UserId", p.Ename);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_LocationId", SqlString.Null);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_DeptId", SqlString.Null);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i_Extension", SqlInt32.Null);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_MainCat", SqlString.Null);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_SubCat", SqlString.Null);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_Item", SqlString.Null);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_Subject", SqlString.Null);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s_Description", SqlString.Null);


            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adpt.Fill(ds);
            if (ds != null)
            {
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string val = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    return val;
                }
            }

        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            con.Close();
            string exep = ex.Message;
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I guess it will be clear now

Comment: You say "there can be problem generating the id" but don't give details. What kind of problem? Your question is not very clear. Please read this: http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Post the code for the function that generates the ID.

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about that , use the auto key geerated by database, it will automatically care of concurrecy issues.

Comment: It's hard to answer the question without seeing the GetId stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need not worry about synchronization here. Your database will do that for you. I am positive.

Thanks,
Krishna